# Adding <Esc> to a remap literally inserts <Esc> into the file

Tags: vimrc, escape

I'm remapping `o` and `O` in my Git Bash `vimrc` to insert a new line without staying in insert mode:

```
nnoremap o o<Esc>
nnoremap O O<Esc>
```

The problem is that a new line is inserted and the literal character sequence `<Esc>` is added onto the new line. How can I fix this, and instead exit insert mode?

Im editing the `etc/vimrc` and this is Git Bash, so it is Git's own version. This path is `local/programs/Git/etc/vimrc` I think. `:version` tells me this is the system `vimrc`, but probably this is only for Git. Also, `:scriptnames` tells me both the `vimrc` and `defaults.vim` are loaded. I've looked through `defaults.vim` but nothing pops out.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120169/discussion-on-question-by-harith-adding-esc-to-a-remap-literally-inserts-esc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Doesn't look like @filbranden or @AndrewHo-Lee are planning to answer this, so adding a Community Wiki answer with [the diagnosis they figured out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120169/discussion-on-question-by-harith-adding-esc-to-a-remap-literally-inserts-esc).)

The problem turned out to be that [`'compatible'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27compatible%27) was set when the mapping was defined.

With this set, the [`'cpoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27cpoptions%27) setting contains [the `<` flag](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#cpo-%3C), which means that Vim will not treat the `<Esc>` in the mapping's `rhs` as a ["special"](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-special) key, and will instead interpret it as the five separate keystrokes: <kbd><</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>></kbd>.

`'compatible'` is set by default. Creating a user `vimrc` will cause it to be unset, but the OP did not have a user `vimrc`, only a system `vimrc`. The fix was to move their configuration from `/etc/vimrc` to `~/.vimrc`. (Manually unsetting `'compatible'` in the system vimrc before defining the mapping would also have worked, as would have using [`<special>`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-special) when defining the mapping.)

Comment: Thanks @Rich for writing this up!

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer:

Using `:substitute` to replace end/beginning of line with return got the results OP wanted.

```
nnoremap o :s/$/\r/ <cr>
nnoremap O :s/^/\r/ <cr>
```

---

Original answer:

I can't get just `o` to be remapped without a recursive error. But a reasonable compromise you might consider from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16136133/13020139) is to use `oo` for new line. This leaves single `o` intact if you do want to go into insert mode.

```
nmap oo o<Esc>
nmap OO O<Esc>
```

Comment: The recursive error you're seeing is because you're using `nmap` instead of `nnoremap` (which will call the _original_ `o` instead of recursively calling your mapping. I'm afraid your solution will have the same problem as the OP's original mapping.

Comment: `nnoremap o :norm o<cr>` was what I was originally going for, but I get that "command too recursive" error.

Comment: That's because `:norm` is then invoking your `o` mapping recursively. Add an exclamation point `:norm!` to avoid the recursion. Nonetheless, none of your solutions will solve the OP's issue, which is that they inadvertently had `'compatible'` set. See [the discussion in :chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120169/discussion-on-question-by-harith-adding-esc-to-a-remap-literally-inserts-esc) where @AndrewHo-Lee and @filbranden figured this out.